# ColdFusion logging vs performance

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am wondering what kind of performance hit I can expect if I enable logging for the following two logs in ColdFusion 8 on a IIS webserver connected to sql 2005 server.

- Log slow pages taking longer than
- Enable logging for scheduled tasks

Comment: I would say comparative to the types of requests under scrunity (already slow ones; occasionally-run ones), the overhead would be negligible. Logging this stuff is fairly common practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a very subjective question and depends on your settings, architecture and loads. Generally, logging takes a very small portion of your server's processing in comparison to everything else it does, however the amount of logging and your log retention policy can affect your server's performance if not tuned properly.

With those caveats in mind, I will attempt to address each setting:

1. Slow Pages logging: Depends on your threshold for slow pages, and if your threshold is reasonable and all your pages are being logged, then the performance issue would likely be on the pages themselves, not the logging of said pages.
2. Scheduled Tasks: Depending on the amount of scheduled tasks and the execution intervals each scheduled task is set to run, the logging of the execution takes up very little space in the logs, and the only real issue would be size and retention policy of the logs.

Answer (score -1):

You can launch the server monitor and it won't have any impact on your server at all.
That would at least let you see what's going on in real time.

Comment: This is a very dangerous answer. The server monitor which ships with ColdFusion is not appropriate to use in production as it adds a *huge* performance and resource overhead. It's almost a guaranteed (oxymoron?) way of bringing down a server.

Comment: Wait @AdamCameron, that's not true is it? I'm talking about the Adobe Flash application that you can see under "Server monitoring", "Server monitor", not turning on the "Enable monitoring server" under "Server monitor", "Settings".  Charlie told me that I could run the Adobe Flash application and it would have zero footprint.

Comment: Depends on how much of it you enable. There's some stuff one can monitor passively, but the active stuff is not fit for purpose. That said: whatever Charlie suggests will be accurate.